# RxJS: Progress bar with countdown

Tags: ionic-framework, rxjs

I am trying to make a button with progress bar and text underneath the button that will tell how much time left. I am using ionic progress bar that take value between [0 ... 1].

```js
public timeToClose = 5 * 1000;

...

const interval = this.timeToClose / 100;
    timer(0, interval).pipe(
      tap((v) => this.progress = v / 100),
      map(i => this.timeToClose - i * interval),
      take(100),
      tap((timeLeft) => this.timeLeft = Math.floor(timeLeft / 1000) + 1),
      finalize(() => this.closeModal()),
    ).subscribe();
```

But this looks awfull. How can i make it better code?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that:

```js
of(5).pipe( // <- time in seconds we want the delay.
    map(v => v * 1000),
    switchMap(delay => {
        const start = new Date().getTime();
        return timer(0, 250).pipe( // <- speed of updates.
            map(() => (new Date().getTime() - start) / delay),
            takeWhile(result => result < 1, true),
        );
    }),
    tap(v => this.progress = v), // <- your stuff
    finalize(() => this.closeModal()), // <- your stuff
).subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks. Intresting implementation.

Comment: thanks, I would even keep it as an observable and subscribed in the template with the async pipe. Because the goal of rx is to keep data flow inside streams.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a different approach:

```js
    // Total amount of steps
    const steps = 9;
    // Total "loading" time in milliseconds
    const totalTimeMs = 3000;

    interval(totalTimeMs / steps).pipe(
      take(steps), 
      map(step => step + 1), 
      tap(step => {
          const progressPercent = step / steps * 100;
          // update your progress bar
    })).subscribe();
```